# what is the meaning of . = and = . in arm assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am new to ARM assembly programming language. I have read a small tutorial about ARM assembly but i think that is not enough . I saw two instructions which i am not able to understand :

1. . = 0x8000
2. _start = .

Can anybody make me understand the meaning of these two instructions and give me the good link / guide for learning ARM assembly language programming ?

Comment: Which assembler are you using? GNU AS? Those aren't ARM instructions; they're directives to the assembler.

Comment: write now m not writing code , m reading codes and trying to understand them ... @Michael

Comment: as for ARM assembly learning: try http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroARM.html

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the symbol that evaluates to the current address.  So that means _start really begins at address 0x8000.  But it really depends on the assembler you are using.

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.html#Dot